# Enterprise Architect - how to change the status to multiple requirement items

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to manage multiple items at once?

For instance: can I select a few requirements from the package browser and mark them all as "approved" (potentially append to them a tag all at once) without going one by one.

So far, I was not able to locate any such option/way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this on a package level(for version below 13) by the following method:

Update the status of all elements in a package and its child packages using
 "Package Control" | "Update Package Status".

Right click on a package from project browser from context menu pick "Package Control"

By writing your own scripts you can change the status of particular elements in the model

Refer this tutorial for more tips: 
http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/760-enterprise-architect-tips-compilation1

also check

http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/770-enterprise-architect-tips-compilation-2

For EA 13 Click Package in Project Browser | Context Menu | Advanced | Update package status will work. 
Hope this will help you.

Regards
Nabil

Comment: Hi Nabil,thank you for you answer - this works indeed for the whole package, but if I wanted to do exactly this just for some items in the package, this will not work. Imagine I have 20 requirements in a package in the state "Proposed" and the client approves 10 of them - currently I need to go to each of them and approve it manually, as there is nothing such as selecting the 10 of them and marking them all as approved, without touching the other ones. Am I correct?

Comment: yes Gianluca you are right, in this case you can move those 10 requirements into one package  and modify the status and again move into the old package this is just a work around. hope this will make the work simple

Comment: On EA v13 its available as Project Browser | Right-click on Package | Advanced | Update Package Status

Answer (score 1):

I've written such a script, [Set Status.vbs](https://github.com/baerrach/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/blob/baerrach/baerrach/Element/Set%20Status.vbs), that will change all selected objects on a diagram to the specified status.

Its still junky because it uses an InputBox to prompt for the desired Status.
While the list of statuses is available in the InputBox you can't copy-and-paste from the dialog.

At least the default value is Approved.

Answer (score 0):

The images appear to no longer exist for the tutorials in the accepted answer, but I came across [this post](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1427040005) that provides a pretty simple tutorial for changing multiple element properties that is easy to change based on your own requirements.

In case the link ever goes dead, I'll re-post it here:

1. Open scripting.
2. Create or open project browser group
3. Create script "Mulit-update Alias" in that group:

(tested in EA 12 and 12.1)

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript
!INC EAScriptLib.JScript-Dialog

/*
 * Script Name: Multielement update
 * 
 * Author: tkazimie
 * Purpose: Update alias field for muli-selected elements project browser
 * Date: 2015.10.23
 *
 * Select elements in Project Browsera, right click and choose "Scripts / Mulit-update Alias" from the context menu
 *
 *
 */
function OnProjectBrowserScript()
{
     // Get the type of element selected in the Project Browser
     var selElem as EA.Collection;

     var wart=DLGInputBox( 'New alias', 'Multi-select element update', '');

     selElem = Repository.GetTreeSelectedElements();
     for (i=0; i < selElem.Count; i++) {
           var e as EA.Element;
           e = selElem.GetAt(i);
           Session.Output('Element changed:'+e.Name);
           e.Alias = wart;
           e.Update();
           e.Refresh();
     }
}

OnProjectBrowserScript();
```